# What is the purpose of RequestMonitorModule and how to use it?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, iis-8, iis-10

I m curious about the purpose of `RequestMonitorModule`. it's seam that with or without it we can see the list of running processes under IIS management console. So I don't quite understand the purpose of this module ?

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the server role itself:

> Request Monitor provides infrastructure to monitor Web application health by capturing information about HTTP requests in an IIS worker process. Administrators and developers can use Request Monitor to understand which HTTP requests are executing in a worker process when the worker process has become unresponsive or very slow.

So to answer your question, Request Monitor allows the you to **view the actual HTTP requests that an IIS worker process is currently handling**, not just a list of the processes.